# Is there really a resource leak if I close the underlying stream?

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream, resource-leak

I ran a dynamic code analysis tool on one of our programs and this pattern was identified as a resource leak:

```
...
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    data = someMethod(new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
    // Assume that someMethod(InputStream) internally reads the stream
    // until BufferedInputStream.read() returns -1.
    ...
}
finally {
    ...
    try {
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Specifically, the analysis tool marked the `new BufferedInputStream(...)` call as a resource leak because it is never closed.  In this pattern, however, the underlying stream `fileInputStream` is closed and the `BufferedInputStream` goes out of scope.

*Note: I neglected to make it clear when I originally posted the question, but I realize this is not the "best" implementation. However, if there is not a de-facto resource leak here then it is unlikely that we will scour our legacy codebase for all instances of this pattern and close the outer streams or replace them with newer constructs such as try-with-resources--i.e., "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."*

Given this situation, is this actually a resource leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no resource leak in this case.  However, the cost of closing the `BufferedInputStream` instead (or as well) is minimal, so it is simplest to add a (strictly) unnecessary close to make the analysis tool happy.

Typical static analysis tools are looking for structural patterns in the code that indicate bugs.  In this case, the pattern matching approach is giving a false positive for a resource leak.

Comment: I haven't finished reviewing all the results from the tool's static analyzer, but this particular case was detected by dynamic analysis.  In any case, it's good to know it isn't a de-facto resource leak since I suspect wrapping an InputStream with BufferedInputStream (possibly without closing it) as a performance optimization has been a fairly common practice in the company.

Answer (score 3):

Its unlikely this is an actual resource leak, but writing code like this is definitely not a best practice.

In general, you should always call `close` on the outermost stream, which will ripple to the inner streams.

If you are using Java 7, you can use the new try-with-resources syntax and avoid using a finally block at all.

**Related:** [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thanks; for the general case try-with-resources is a good recommendation. However, in my particular case it's unlikely that we will budget time to find and update all instances of this pattern in our existing codebase unless there is a significant, de-facto resource leak. My secondary goal is probably not relevant to most people, but I'm also trying to determine whether the analysis tool is finding real bugs or if its heuristics are flagging false-positives as bugs.

Comment: @rob I think the issue is that you don't know for sure whether or not a resource leak is occuring without looking at the implementation for someMethod.  I agree with Stephen that for most reasonable implementations it won't be an issue.

Comment: @rob My general rule for stylistic changes like this is to clean them up a little bit at a time as you come across them.  I agree with you that there is no point in declaring a company wide mandate to change this pattern overnight.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java has no deconstructors, the object going out of scope will not necessarily close the stream. Java does have finalizers, but there is no guarantee they will be called. The BufferedInputStream will not necessarily be closed. However because the underlying stream is closed I don't really think it matters.

It's better practice to ensure that the stream is closed, but it *probably* doesn't matter.